# CKEditor 4 removes xlink:href in A tags even when allowedContent set to true

Tags: ckeditor

I have to use CKEditor to allow users to edit some HTLM pages that may include SVG images. And the links defined in those SVG images contain some attribute like xlink:href. E.g:

```
    <svg preserveaspectratio="xMinYMin meet" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 778 873" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
    <image height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="map.png"></image> 
        <g class="hover_group" opacity="1"> 
            <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
                <rect fill="red" height="100" opacity="0.0" width="160" x="110" y="240"></rect> 
            </a> 
        </g> 
    </svg>
```

I already set CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true with hope that all tags and attributes will be retained by the editor.

However, when I switch back and forth between WYSIWYG and HTML mode, I notice that the A tag become like this:

**a href="http://www.google.com" xlink:=""**

```
<svg preserveaspectratio="xMinYMin meet" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 778 873" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
    <image height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="map.png"></image> 
    <g class="hover_group" opacity="1"> 
        <a href="http://www.google.com" xlink:="">
            <rect fill="red" height="100" opacity="0.0" width="160" x="110" y="240"></rect> 
        </a> 
    </g> 
</svg>
```

This behavior only happens to the A tag, not the IMAGE tag.

Of course, this makes the link in SVG file no longer work.

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks. I don't want to manually allow all the allowed tags or attributes because this may be so much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug (called also "lack of feature") in CKEditor. It's not able to process attributes ending with ":href" properly.

I reported http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13233 which also includes a possible patch. If it's correct, then this issue will be fixed in the next minor release.

Comment: Thanks. Update ckeditor.js with the recommended regular expression and it's working fine now.

`/([\w-:]+)\s*=\s*(?:(?:"[^"]*")|(?:'[^']*')|(?:[^ "'>]+))/gi`

Comment: @ tala9999 Can you please post your working ckeditor.js? I've tried editing with your example, but the ckeditor is breaking.